# QGIS is not showing/rendering points that are present in MySQL server

Tags: qgis, point, mysql

I have a MySQL database in which there are auto generated points almost 1000 created via Laravel (PHP framework) it has a very simple schema as shown below. I just want to visualise them on an OpenStreetMap map in QGIS,

[image]

I did add a vector layer and set the source to be my points table
The points do not show on the map, but when I open attributes table and then keep moving to next feature from the attributes table window the QGIS blinks red circles on the display indicating that there are points there. But unfortunately it does not render and I have been struggling for a while to get them displayed. I have attached another screen shot showing when it blinks them. I am new to QGIS.

[image]

**UPDATE :** 
After doing a lot of search and experiments with changing data inserting it manually in mysql using different variations, turns out this is an OLD QGIS Bug. There is a work around to to make it render the data but then it won't allow you to edit the data.

Here is the link, issue already reported but not yet fixed as I tested in QGIS 3.10 version

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20563
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28383

Comment: Hi Ahmed. I would like a little more information: can you please give us the coordinates and projection information of some of the coordinates you want to show? Could you show us how qgis is set up to display your points? Do I understand your last figure correctly that point #3 is located approximately on the border between South Africa, Botswana and Zimbabwe?

Comment: @MortenSickel its is bug, I have updated my post, please read the update section

Answer (score 0):

And the moment after I had written the comment, I think I understand what might be the problem: Check if you are displaying your world map on top of your points.

In the layer window, your points should be above the world map. To do a quick check, just uncheck the box beside the world map to temporary turn it off.

Comment: No, that is not the case, I have done more research and turns out it is a bug in QGIS when importing mySQL data sometimes it does not display the geometry data

Comment: That's a pity. Would it be possible for you to use postgresql / postgis in stead?

Comment: The main project needs mySQL due to other requirements, therefore do not have this option yet..otherwise I would have preferred that. Primarily due to scaling of database for example mysql provides master slave and master master configurations also, we need to have that in the project so the choice was mysql, I wanted to have 2 dbs one for non geospatial needs and one for spatial and wanted to choose postgres that would just another complexity in the app